# Child Div's bottom goes outside parent Div

Tags: html, css

I cant find out why my #ContenedorTipoInversionDiv finishes bellow its parent #SectionInvest. 
The problem seems to happen only in the bottom, because the top of #ContenedorTipoInversion starts just after a navbar (a div before the code I posted)

```css
.TipoInversion { 
    height:100%;
    margin:0%10%0%10%;
    display:inline-block;
}

#ContenedorTipoInversion
{
    padding:15% 0% 15% 0%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    width:100%;
    display:inline-block;
}

#SectionInvest {
    background-image: url("../img/Backgrounds/InvestBackground.jpg");
    background-size:     cover;
    background-repeat:   no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    max-height: 100%;
    height: 100vh; 
}
```

```html
<div class="content">  
    <section id = "SectionInvest">
        <div id = "ContenedorTipoInversion">
            <div class = "TipoInversion" id = "BajoRiesgo">Bajo riesgo</div>
            <div class = "TipoInversion" id = "Balanceado">Balanceado</div>
            <div class = "TipoInversion" id = "Agresivo">Agresivo</div>
        </div>   
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You put height for #ContenedorTipoInvestion to 100%, and height to SectionInvest to `height: 100vh;`

```css
.TipoInversion { 
 height:100%;
 margin:0%10%0%10%;
 display:inline-block;
}

#ContenedorTipoInversion
{
 padding:15% 0% 15% 0%;
 height:100%;
 margin:0;
 width:100%;
 display:inline-block;
}

#SectionInvest {
 background-image: url("../img/Backgrounds/InvestBackground.jpg");
 background-size:     cover;
  background-repeat:   no-repeat;
 background-position: 50% 50%;
 max-height: 100%; 
}
```

```html
<div class="content">  
   <section id = "SectionInvest">
    <div id = "ContenedorTipoInversion">
     <div class = "TipoInversion" id = "BajoRiesgo">Bajo riesgo</div>
     <div class = "TipoInversion" id = "Balanceado">Balanceado</div>
     <div class = "TipoInversion" id = "Agresivo">Agresivo</div>
    </div>   
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem, I want that the parent #SectionInvest fit to all the browser window (100vh), and the child to be kep inside it height: 100%. Am I missing a CSS property?

Answer (score 0):

Just add `box-sizing: border-box;` to include the padding *within* the `height` and `width` measurements (by default it's *added*  to height and width):

(note that the snippet box is too low to allow a correct display - open it at full size)

```css
* {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.TipoInversion { 
    height:100%;
    margin:0%10%0%10%;
    display:inline-block;
}

#ContenedorTipoInversion
{
    padding:15% 0% 15% 0%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    width:100%;
    display:inline-block;
}

#SectionInvest {
    background-image: url("../img/Backgrounds/InvestBackground.jpg");
    background-size:     cover;
    background-repeat:   no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    max-height: 100%;
    height: 100vh; 
}
```

```html
<div class="content">  
    <section id = "SectionInvest">
        <div id = "ContenedorTipoInversion">
            <div class = "TipoInversion" id = "BajoRiesgo">Bajo riesgo</div>
            <div class = "TipoInversion" id = "Balanceado">Balanceado</div>
            <div class = "TipoInversion" id = "Agresivo">Agresivo</div>
        </div>   
</div>
```